# Function to integrate multiple plots into one widget

Tags: java, pandas, matplotlib, plot

On pandas, I have 4 contour plots (using the kdeplot function) but I want to integrate them into one plot, preferably in a 2x2 square. Is there any function/code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `plt.subplots`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(10),'B':np.arange(10)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4, figsize=[10,10])
axes = ax.flatten()
 
for i in range(16):
    df.plot(x='A',y='B', ax=axes[i])
    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for a 4*4 kdeplot:

```
w = [.001,.002,.003,.004,.005,.006,.007,.008,.009,.01,.02,.03,.04,.05,.06,.07] 
plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
for i,j in enumerate(w):
    plt.subplot(4,4,i+1)
    sns.kdeplot(df['lbl'],bw=j,label="bw-"+str(j))
    plt.xlabel('lbl')
    plt.legend()
```

Plots:

[image]

For 2*2 plot, use the below code

```
w = [.001,.002,.003,.004] 
plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
for i,j in enumerate(w):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1)
    sns.kdeplot(df['lbl'],bw=j,label="bw-"+str(j))
    plt.xlabel('lbl')
    plt.legend()
```

[image]